# what oil for daily fork tube lubrication?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork

Some guy tells me to use "silk honey" for my fork tube.
But it's hard to come by from where I am.

Any good stuff you guys use?
Can I use RockShox 5/15wt damper oil?

All my bike use RockShox by the way.

Comment: *Daily* lubrication?

Comment: Your fork's manual should have service intervals. Follow them. The intervals will be such that almost nobody needs to lubricate daily.

Comment: I have a memory that fork service intervals are every 30-50 hours of riding - you're doing 2 days riding a day every day?   I don't ever lube my forks cos none have suspension.

Comment: Lubricate dust seals and upper tubes - Every ride. Rockshox manual say so.  I'm sure it's base on dirtyest ride. I said daily, it's my bad making it sound confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Slick Honey" is actually a grease, not an oil. It will be applied to rubber seals which get in touch with the tubes and thereby with dust, mud, etc. The Rock Shox 5w/15 oil is maiused inside of the fork but also for the (foam) dust wipers within the rubber top caps of the fork.

Anyway. 
Instead of "Slick Honey" you can also use "r.s.p. SlickKick Grease", "SRAM Butter" or "SRAM PM600 Military Grease" for service according to service intervals.
If the fork does not run smooth you could apply a bit of products such as "Finish Line Max Suspension Spray" after bike wash – but there are mixed opinions on stuff like that.

Personally I try to keep the tubes clean, wipe the off after every mud/dirt ride. If there is a week of heavy riding ahead, but last service is not too long ago, I sometimes apply 5w/15 oil on the tubes: http://enduro-mtb.com/en/how-to-the-quick-suspension-service-after-each-tour/

Happy riding!

Answer (score 3):

For an average user, lubricating the fork tube on a regular basis is not really necessary. Follow your instruction manual.

More important is to keep fork tubes clean. Dry, hard mud, insects and other stuff like that which sticks to the tube surface can potentially damage the oil seal. To prevent this, use proper dust sealants.

Lubricating the fork tube surface to reduce sealant friction is not a bad idea, but fork oil is not the best option. It is sticky, makes dust stay on the tube and gets between the seal and tube. This works akin to sandpaper and damages the chromed surface.

If you really want, use dedicated products, like [Ariete ARISIL](http://www.northern.co.nz/products/164-grease_and_lubricants/3725-ariete_arisil_special_fork_oil.aspx)

Comment: Makes me wonder why stanchion boots became unfashionable.  I mean - cars have CV boots to protect the moving parts.